# Is db4o Java 8 compatible?

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, deserialization, db4o

Have side project that is using db4o. It's doesn't work with JVM 8 (on deserialising getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.xxx.yyy.version to com.db4o.reflect.generic.GenericObject`).

1. Is it possible to fix it for JVM 8 (and yes, I know that db4o is dead)?
2. What to use instead of db4o for JVM version independent serialisation/de-serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer:**
Db4o IS compliant Java 8. It was hibernate proxy issue (Javassist and dynamic classes) :(

***Update 07/20/15:*** Not sure that db4o is 100% correctly works under JVM 8. We have a strange test case that we cannot explain (see below). At the same time native Java serialisation works correctly (but db4o doesn't).

**Full answer:**
If someone need details, this issue appears in Hibernate 4.3 (in previous versions everything works as expected). Unfortunately, I didn't find correct solution. Quick and dirty workaround is to skip problem fields from exporting to db4o (via `transient` keyword).

**Update 07/30/15:** Found a solution (the issue appears in Javassist 1.8):

```
ProxyFactory.nameGenerator = new JavassitBackwardCompatibleNamingGenerator();

public class JavassitBackwardCompatibleNamingGenerator implements UniqueName{
    private static int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public String get(String classname) {
        return classname + "_$$_javassist_" + counter++;
    }
}
```